# In R , a question about dplyr::bind_rows combine dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

There are dataframes in R , which name like `data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 ....`,  below code combine all of them failed . How to fixed it ? Thanks1

```
dplyr::bind_rows(ls(pattern = "data*"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "data*")))
```

or

```
data.table::rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "data*")))
```

We only get strings from `ls(pattern = "data*")`, and need to convert those strings to objects using `mget`.